# let vim tab title be the current directory name

Tags: vim, tabs, project

Given that vim tabs are not intended to be used the same way as tabs are used in TextMate, Sublime, etc. I am planning to start using them as suggested [here](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/how-to-use-tabs/), where each tab could represent a different project or folder.

For instance, I'm currently working on a Rails app that is split into different projects that interact with each other, and I also occasionally browse someone else's gem source to see how it works, etc. I could then try to work in a way so that each open tab correspond to a different project, taking advantage of the fact that each tab can be associated to a different working directory.

Therefore I would appreciate any recommendations on how to achieve using vim properly in this manner, and if it makes sense. **In particular, I am looking for a way to customize vim so that the tab title shows the name of the current directory for that tab, instead of the name of the currently active buffer within that tab.**

Comment: Looks like you can build a function for `:set tabline` to use

Comment: For CLI Vim, see `:h seeting-tabline`; for GUI Vim, see `:h setting-guitablabel`.

Comment: So is there a distinction between how it works in gui and cli? Can I setup both in the .vimrc once I figure them out? Or do I have to work out some conditional statements so that only the right one is setup in each case?

Comment: Hmm, there's a typo in my comment, sorry. Yeah you'll need a conditional; something like `if has('gui_running') ... elseif ... endif`.

Comment: I personally dislike how vim implemented tabs.  I feel that they should really have their own environment (i.e. its own set of variables, registers, loaded buffers, history and current directory).  You can have one tab be in a different directory from another tab, if you use `:lcd`.  I wish I could have answered your question, but I don't think there is a clean way to do what you are looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for gvim, but you should be able to make it work in a terminal vim easily:

All in your .vimrc:

```
function! GuiTabLabel()
     return substitute( expand( '%:p' ), '.\+\/\(.\+\)\/.\+', '\1', '' )
 endfunction
 set guitablabel=%{GuiTabLabel()}
```

It's not pretty, the path separator is hard-coded and I find the resulting tab labels odd to work with, but I guess it's at least a starting point.